# Simulation in express mode takes a lot of time

Tags: omnet++

I am launching a simulation of clone detection attack in WSN with host number as parameter that takes 50, 100, 150, 200, 250 and 300 as a value. I run the simulation in express mode and wait until an attack is detected and the simulation stops. my problem is that from 150 nodes, the run time is very long ( in about a minute only 90ms are passed in the simulation runtime on the field at the top of the window. Is there anyway to accelerate the simulation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, build your project in release mode (default mode is debug). Then, turn off recording of vectors (unless you really need vectors). And start your simulation in Cmdenv mode.